What makes Simulated Annealing more likely in finding a more-optimal solution than Hill-Climbing?
I have a question similar to that of this post Simulated Annealing - Intuition but wasn't satisfied/didn't understand the answers.
I understand that both algorithms are very likely to end up stuck in local maxima/minima. I don't understand, though, how simulated annealing's usage of tempurature and exploration increases its odds of finding a solution closer to the global maximum/minimum. Wouldn't accepting a worse solution to explore the solution space have an equal chance of entering a worse local minima/maxima than entering a better one?
Similarly, I know you can concurrently store the most optimal solution found in simulated annealing, and thus, are free to explore the solution space without the risk of getting stuck with a worse solution. But what makes this better than just calling multiple instances of the hill-climbing algorithm? Wouldn't both algorithms explore the solution space and return the most optimal solution found?
I think my mis-understanding lies within simulated annealing's exploration process. To me, it seems like an arbitrary step, with no inherent benefits to that of the hill climbing algorithm.
I've tried my best in researching these algorithms, but they all say the same thing: "accepting a worse solution gives it a better chance at finding an even better one". As explained above, I understand that it is possible to find a better one, but wouldn't it just as likely find a inferior one?

"just as likely" is the crux. No the probability of jumping to a worse solution decreases with how worse that solution is. So if local minimum A is worse than local minimum B with barrier C between them, you are more likely to jump over C from A (then and fall to B) than to jump over C from B (then fall back to A).

appreciate this---clears up my misconception. thank you.

It is difficult to get a feel for the objective to be optimized; usually, it involves multi-dimensional, spiky landscapes with anomalies like mirrors and black holes.
Even for smooth two-dimensional surfaces, hill climbing can get 'sucked' into a local minimum. Without any knowledge of the objective, it is not evident how to 'throw' the algorithm out of a local minimum. You probably have to:

Develop an intuition about which method is best to kick it out.
Understand how far away you need to kick him out of the local minimum.
Find the right costs allowed to escape a local minima, in different phases of solution finding.
Come up with a cost-effective method to determine if you are stuck in a local minimum (for larger objectives, this is not so evident, waiting until all neighbours fail might take too long).

Simulated Annealing's strength is that by combining temperature and acceptance, it automatically addresses the above points. Notice that by design, it will always find a 'cheap' route to walk out of a local minimum if possible.
At some phase during annealing, the balance between temperature and acceptance is just right, allowing improvement without much risk getting stuck in a local minimum. One of its strong points is that you don't need to know where this phase is; you can start with a high temperature and end with a low one, and somewhere along the cooling the balance is just right.
In short, hill climbing will get sucked into a local minimum, and it is not so evident how to 'tinker' the algorithm into a version that, regardless of the problem, achieves the right balance between exploration and exploitation. Once you tackle these problems somehow, you will probably end up with ideas similar to simulated annealing.

Simulated annealing (SA) like hill-climbing is an algorithm aimed at finding the global minimum of a function E(x0, ..., xn) for a given region ω(x0, ..., xn). The function to be minimized can be interpreted as the system energy.
SA works by randomly selecting a new point (y0, ..., yn) in the neighbourhood of the current solution, evaluating the energy function E(y0,  ..., yn), and deciding if the new solution is accepted or rejected:

If ΔE = E - Emin < 0 ,where Emin is a previously found energy minimum, the new solution is accepted with probability: 1.0.

If ΔE > 0, the new solution is accepted with probability: P(ΔE > 0, T) > 0.
This is the crucial part that distinguishes hill-climbing from SA.
Accepting up-hill moves provides a method of escaping from local energy minima. See image below (source: simulated annealing):



The acceptance probability for solutions satisfying ΔE > 0 is often chosen to be P(ΔE > 0, T) = exp(-ΔE/T). It decreases with decreasing temperature. As such, the temperature is a parameter that controls the probability of up-hill moves.
SA involves an "outer" iteration (where the temperature is reduced according to some annealing schedule) and a series of "inner" iterations where the search space is explored at constant temperature.
In practice, the temperature is chosen such that initially the probability of up-hill moves is high (say 0.7) and the search region includes the whole search space. As the temperature is reduced the probability of uphill moves decreases and the search region is contracted around the "global" minimum.
Note that convergence to a global minimum is not strictly guaranteed and it is advisable to tune the algorithm by playing around with different annealing schedules, initial temperature, number of "inner" iterations, etc.
